# Android http requests and javascript

Tags: android, http

I want to provide a better interface to a web browser game - dedicated to Android. The game uses javascript and a bit of flash (so simple that it appears in webview correctly). It has lots of images that make the page load for ages on my device.
My first idea was to make a webview GONE, but it doesn't solve my problem that page loads really long.
My second idea is to use something like HttpClient (any advices?) to get HTML code of site and then parse it (all data that I need is there). BUT here comes two troubles:

1) How can I handle cookies? Is it hard?

2) How can I execute javascript without a WebView?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to create HTTP(s) request. Take a look at [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class.
There is an exemple how to handle cookies.
Here you can find a [quick introduction to the HttpURLConnection](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html).

You won't be able to execute javascript. But if you are creating an app for you webapp you will need to recreate the behaviour. The javascript is useless with a native app.

Comment: The problem is - it is not mine game ;) So I have to use WebView or record network traffic and analyse it to recreate actions taken by javascript? Will the second approach work?

Comment: With developper tools in firefox or chrome you will be able to reverse javascript call.

Comment: Javascript in a webapp will be use :
 1) To send xmlhttprequest to server in order to retrive data/information


 2) To refresh HMI

For the fisrt part you need to reverse http request and the second part is up to you in your app.